# UpdatePanel for literal controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel that uses AJAX in ASP.NET that updates a gridview whenenever a user inserts a new row, deletes a row, or updates a row and reflects the changes without refreshing the page.

I have a couple of literal controls that collects row information on the gridview and I was wondering if there was a way to have these update when the gridview is updated (asyncpostback).  I tried adding my literal controls as triggers and including them in the update panel but I received an error.

I have added my code, and I would like the div at the top of the code (literal controls) to be udpated asynchronously whenever the gridview is updated.  Is this possible?

**ASP.NET CODE:**

```
<div id="Div1" style="float:right; margin-right: 100px; margin-bottom: 45px;">
   <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   <br />
   <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   <br />
   <asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   </div>
        <div id="dvGrid" style="padding: 0px">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" width="100%" EditRowStyle-Width="100px" DataKeyNames="PersonID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12pt"
                        ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="EditCustomer" OnRowUpdating="UpdateCustomer"
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Height="95px">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" # "> 
                                <ItemTemplate>

                                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>

                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server"  Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="gridTextBox" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" width="60px"  MaxLength="15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Last Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>

                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="gridTextBox" Text='<%# Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" width="60px" MaxLength="15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Age">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" CssClass="gridTextBox" Text='<%# Eval("Age")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" Width="30px" MaxLength="2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Activity Card">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblActivityCard" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActivityCard")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtActivityCard"  CssClass="gridTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActivityCard")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtActivityCard" Width="50px" MaxLength="7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Cell Phone">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCell" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cell#")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCell" runat="server"  CssClass="gridTextBox" Text='<%# Eval("Cell#")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCell" Width="70px" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Emergency Phone">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmergency" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Emergency#")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmergency" runat="server"  CssClass="gridTextBox" Text='<%# Eval("Emergency#")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmergency" width="70px" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>               
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Boat Type">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblBoat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CraftType")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoat" runat="server" CssClass="gridTextBox" Text='<%# Eval("CraftType")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBoat" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem>None</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Kayak</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Canoe</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Initials">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblInitials" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Initials")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInitials" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Initials")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInitials" width="30px" MaxLength="2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Group #">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group#")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group#")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroup" MaxLength="2" Width="20px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PersonID")%>'
                                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" Text="Delete"
                                        OnClick="DeleteCustomer"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </itemtemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="AddNewCustomer" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: Blue;">No records are available matching your selected filter. Click on "Add" button to enter new data .. </span>               
  </EmptyDataTemplate>

                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Aqua" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1"/>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Just a friendly hit: you should consider posting a code snippet that is representative of your problem, otherwise it will far more difficult to help you

Comment: Yep, as @AndreaScarcella said, can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: @AndreaScarcella Thanks for the feedback, my code has been added.

Comment: What exactly is the error you receive?